# Pandas: use apply / applymap to calculate difference and increase counter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am trying to replace a loop iterating through pandas dataframe with a faster approach, but not sure how to apply lambda with map to make it work as intended.

I have a dataframe with prices - for instance:

```
                       open    high     low   close
timestamp                                          
2018-02-07 18:00:00  8341.0  8460.5  8255.0  8255.0
2018-02-07 19:00:00  8250.0  8270.0  8033.5  8179.0
2018-02-07 20:00:00  8183.0  8225.0  7972.5  8165.0
2018-02-07 21:00:00  8154.0  8289.0  8024.0  8078.0
```

For each of the row, I need to check specific conditions, which are currently written as:

```
if ((bars['close'].iloc[i - 1] > bars['close'].iloc[i - 5]) and 
    (bars['close'].iloc[i] < bars['close'].iloc[i - 4])):
```

If the condition is met, I need to increase a counter (mod 9).

Could anyone please advise how the loop checking these conditions can be replaced with more elegant and quick solution? The full code snippet is as follows:

```
## Getting through an dataframe and calculating values 
for i in range(0 + 6, size): # 
    bullish_flip = False 

    if setup_up == 9: 
        setup_up = 0 # restart count 
        nextbar_beyond = False 

    if ((bars['close'].iloc[i - 1] < bars['close'].iloc[i - 5]) 
    and (bars['close'].iloc[i] > bars['close'].iloc[i - 4])): 
        bullish_flip = True     
        direction_up = True        

    if direction_down and bullish_flip: 
        #print 'Bullish flip 1', bars['close'].index[i]
        direction_down = False      
        setup_up = 1 

    if direction_up and not bullish_flip: 
        if (bars['close'].iloc[i] < bars['close'].iloc[i - 4]):  
            setup_up = 1
            nextbar_beyond = False
        else: 
            setup_up += 1
```

Example of the output:

```
                        open     high      low    close  td_setup  \
timestamp                                                            
2018-01-30 19:00:00   9901.5  10251.0   9743.0  10120.0         1   
2018-01-30 23:00:00  10105.0  10105.0   9512.0   9961.0         1   
2018-01-31 03:00:00   9959.0  10093.0   9612.0   9983.5         1   
2018-01-31 07:00:00   9988.0  10230.0   9933.5  10121.0         1   
2018-01-31 11:00:00  10120.5  10327.0   9769.5   9876.0         1   
2018-01-31 15:00:00   9877.0  10048.0   9719.5   9944.0         2   
2018-01-31 19:00:00   9945.0  10112.5   9861.0  10046.5         1   
2018-01-31 23:00:00  10046.0  10195.0   9983.0  10074.5         1   
2018-02-01 03:00:00  10082.5  10167.0   9832.0  10035.5         1   
2018-02-01 07:00:00  10043.0  10094.5   9331.5   9377.5         1   
2018-02-01 11:00:00   9369.5   9567.0   9081.0   9310.0         2   
2018-02-01 15:00:00   9312.5   9336.0   8875.0   8994.0         3   
2018-02-01 19:00:00   8999.5   9234.0   8488.0   8889.0         4   
2018-02-01 23:00:00   8891.5   9098.5   8536.5   8841.5         5   
2018-02-02 03:00:00   8842.0   8914.5   8305.0   8530.0         6   
2018-02-02 07:00:00   8527.5   8681.0   8085.0   8101.0         7   
2018-02-02 11:00:00   8102.0   8826.5   7620.0   8578.5         8   
2018-02-02 15:00:00   8648.0   9050.0   8464.0   8545.0         9
```

Comment: Expected output would be helpful here.

Comment: added an example